# Coalesce across the ID to retrieve Name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| ID | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1 |
| 1 | NULL | 10 |
| 2 | Sam | 11 |
| 3 | Mike | 13 |
| 3 | NULL | 15 |
| 4 | Tom | 80 |
| 5 | Null | 90 |
| 5 | Clare | 10 |
| 6 | NULL | 10 |

The output I'm looking for in SQL/BigQuery

| ID | Name | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 11 |
| 2 | Sam | 11 |
| 3 | Mike | 28 |
| 4 | Tom | 80 |
| 5 | Clare | 100 |
| 6 | NULL | 10 |

I think there is a COALESCE function involved but not sure how to approach this.

If there is a NULL Name, I want the count column to be added + for the NULL Name to be dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT ID, Count, MAX(Name) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) AS New_Name_Column

From Table

Group By 1,2

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE(a,b)` is to combine several columns `a` and `b` to one not null entry.

You want the `any_value` or `max` function and `group by id`

```sql
with tbl as (select 1 id,"John" name,   1 count
union all select 1  ,NULL,  10
union all select 2  ,"Sam", 11
union all select 3  ,"Mike",    13
union all select 3, NULL,   15
union all select 4  ,"Tom", 80
union all select 5  ,Null,  90
union all select 5  ,"Clare",   10
union all select 6  ,NULL,  10)
select id, max(name),sum(count) as counts
from tbl
group by id
```